# ReactJS + Redux: How to directly navigate to a page (skip login) if token is in local storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, redux, react-redux

Currently in my root component, it is set to go directly to the Login page as default. But I would like to set it up where it checks to see if a token already exists in the local storage, and if it does, skip the Login page and navigate directly to the Home page.

With the following code I have set up, it navigates to the Home page but for a split second the Login page appears before navigating to the Home page.

How can I go directly to the Home page without the Home page showing up at all?

**Here is the code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import configureStore from '../redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import cookie from 'react-cookie';

import actions from '../redux/actions'
import Login from '../components/Login'
import App from '../components/App'
import Home from '../components/Home'

let store = configureStore(initialState)

//Takes the token from local storage and set to const token
const token = cookie.load('token');

//This checks to see if the token exists in the local storage, and if it does, it enters the if statement and goes directly to the Home component.
if(token) {
  window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/#/App'
}

render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route
          component={Login}
          path='/'
        />
        <Route
          component={App}
          path='App'
        >
          <IndexRoute
            component={Home}
          />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Check token in `componentWillMount` function in `LoginComponent` and if there is a token use React-Router API to navigate to home

Comment: @niba Probably worth submitting that as an answer and go into a little more detail. That'll definitely sort this out, but might be good to have a proper answer for future readers!

Comment: i use push method --- import {push} from 'react-router-redux' for manual redirect

Comment: @abhirathore2006 Sorry but for clarification could you show as an answer with the code that I've provided? So I can upvote and accept the answer as well. Thank you

Comment: i posted answer below  with code and document link.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a root component called LoginCheck, in this component you would use the componentWillMount lifecycle hook to determine whether a user is logged in or not.  If the user is logged in, it would continue to the correct page, otherwise it would redirect to the login page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps.

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

    export class Home extends React.Component{
        constructor(props, context)
        {
            super(props, context);

        }
        componentWillMount() {
          if(token)
          {
            browserHistory.push("YOUR AUTHENTICATED PAGE");
          }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write something like this in component will mount

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
//login component
componentWillMount(){
 if(token){
  this.props.dispatch(push("/home"));
 }
}
```

Explanation from Documentation [React-Router-Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux)

> What if I want to issue navigation events via Redux actions?
>
> React Router provides singleton versions of history (browserHistory
>   and hashHistory) that you can import and use from anywhere in your
>   application. However, if you prefer Redux style actions, the library
>   also provides a set of action creators and a middleware to capture
>   them and redirect them to your history instance.
>
> import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
>   import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
>
> // Apply the middleware to the store const middleware =
>   routerMiddleware(browserHistory) const store = createStore(
>   reducers,   applyMiddleware(middleware) )
>
> // Dispatch from anywhere like normal. store.dispatch(push('/foo'))